# Removing duplicates from list of lists by using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was curious if you could remove duplicates from list of lists and return uniques as a list. I was trying this:

```
def do_list( lists ):
    res = [ [ one for one in temp if one not in res ] for temp in lists ]
    return res
```

So for example, if:

```
lists = [ [ "a","b","c" ],[ "d","a" ],[ "c","a","f" ] ]
```

the result should be:

```
[ "a","b,"c","d","f" ]
```

But it gives me error that I refference variable res before assigment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error because you're referencing `res` inside the comprehension. This doesn't work, since `res` is only available after the expression is finished.

As I'm a curious sort, and because the title asks "Removing duplicates from list of lists by using list comprehension", I wanted to see if you can do this using *only* a list comprehension, and not by *cheating* such as using `itertools` :p

And here's how:

```
>>> lists = [ [ "a","b","c" ],[ "d","a" ],[ "c","a","f" ] ]
>>> lists2 = sorted(sum(lists, []))
>>> [ item for i, item in enumerate(lists2) if i == 0 or i == len(lists2) or lists2[i - 1] != item ]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
```

For more insanity, you can combine them on a single line, but you'd have to repeat the `sum()` and `sorted()` calls. I couldn't move myself to write such ugly code ;-)

- `sum(lists, [])` will flatten the list; it returns the sum (`+` operator) of all the items in `lists`, with `[]` as the initial list.
- `sorted()` will sort it. This is needed since we only check against the last item
- the `if` statement checks if the previous item is the same as the current item.

But it's ugly and un-Pythonic. **For the love of Guido, use Pythonista's answer** (or some variation thereof)!

Comment: @TheTask1337 Not sure if "beautiful" is the right word  to describe this sort of code ;-) It looks like the sort of thing a Perl programmer would do! :p Like I said, it's merely an educational exercise. Please don't actually use it ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You could do this:

```
set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lists))
```

`set` will remove all duplicates, inside of the `set` is just flattening your list(s) to a single list.

Comment: Or `set(itertools.chain(*lists))`, a bit fewer characters.

Comment: Thank you! So is it impossible to do by using just plain list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

`res` isn't created until the entire list comprehension has been evaluated.  You can use a `set` to remove duplicates:

```
res = list(set(sum(lists, [])))
```

If you want it sorted:

```
res = sorted(set(sum(lists, [])))
```

If you want it ordered exactly how it comes, a list comprehension is probably not the best way.  Instead, do this:

```
res = []
for temp in lists:
    res.append([])
    for one in temp:
        if one not in res[-1]:
            res[-1].append(one)
```

Comment: IMHO using `sum(lists, [])` is much more obvious way to create a flattened list...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: It may be obvious, but maybe I don't have a substantial amount of intelligence.  Thanks for mentioning it.